# Cannot unlock password protected SSH key in OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, password, ssh, keychain

I just upgraded to OSX 10.9, and when trying to establish an SSH connection with public key authentication, a prompt appears asking for my SSH key password.

I initially thought that the upgrade caused the keychain to forget some passwords, so I re-entered mine. Apparently, that wasn't the cause, because the prompt kept reappearing.

I first though that I may be using the wrong password, but while the following command:

```
$ ssh-keygen -vvv -y -f id_rsa >| id_rsa.pub
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase:
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
load failed
```

...does not work! If I try to use openssl:

```
$ openssl rsa -in id_rsa -text
Enter pass phrase for id_rsa:
Private-Key: (2048 bit)
modulus:
    00:...
```

my private key is correctly decrypted and all information is printed.

What happened with the upgrade to Mavericks? How can I get my private key back in a usable state?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently, the private key I was using on my machine was an old one. My key did not contain the encryption information added to the private key file if I generate a new one:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-...
```

To solve the problem, I decrypted the key with openssl:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ cp id_rsa id_rsa.bck
$ openssl rsa -in id_rsa -out id_rsa
```

...and then re-encrypted it:

```
$ openssl rsa -in id_rsa -aes256 -out id_rsa
$ chmod 0600 id_rsa
```

And just in case, regenerate the public key as well:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa > id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it by moving .ssh/authorized_keys2 to .ssh/authorized_keys.

The file /etc/sshd_config explicitly contains these lines:

```
\# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
\# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
```

This is a change from previous macosx version?

Comment: This problem is a different one as well. In my case I was not able to decrypt **my** private key.

Answer (score 3):

Using brew openssl and openssh fixes the PCKS#8 issue on Mavericks.

```
brew update
brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force
brew install openssh

# confirm correct bins are being used
# both should be located in /usr/local/bin
which openssl
which openssh

# add key back to keychain
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I'm not sure if force linking openssl breaks anything on Mavricks. So far, I haven't noticed any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, my keys show the same behaviour.

I tracked the problem back to this blog post.
I modified my ssh-keys the way it was described in this artice to increase security and it worked unter Mountain Lion.
http://martin.kleppmann.com/2013/05/24/improving-security-of-ssh-private-keys.html

I assume that Apple changed somthing with openssh and the "new" version is not capable of reading the newer PKCS#8 format.

My Mavericks OpenSSH Version: `OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011`

I have no other Mac so I can't compare it to the Mountain Lion version.

Comment: `/usr/bin/ssh -V` prints `OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011` on my 10.8.0 VM.

Comment: Interessting, If you have time can you check what does "ssh-keygen -vvv -y -f id_rsa" show if you use a pkcs#8 key?

Comment: My pkcs #8 key, derived via that same link, shows this: https://gist.github.com/cbowns/7359383/raw/eddb52633f229fd905397f050fe83b2c01b9d8a7/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by simply doing the following:

```
cd ~/.ssh
mv known_hosts known_hosts.old
```

Now go and connect. When it asks the standard question to add the fingerprint type yes.

Comment: But don't forget to check the fingerprint!

Comment: This is a different problem from what I was asking. The known hosts file has nothing to do with the problem encountered here (decrypting of the private key)

Answer (score 0):

Happened to get this problem. 
By trying to specify the cipher, I was able to get it work well.

On Linux, when you try to generate key pairs, use this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -Z aes256
```

The public key now with cipher aes256 can be correctly recognized by ssh on OSX (here, mine is 10.12.1).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a PuTTY key to an OpenSSL OS X key:

```
puttygen putty.ppk -O private-openssh -o osx.key
```

Type the passphrase and you're done.